# How do I access a json file from a secure website in iOS5?

Tags: json, authentication, ios5

How do I access a json file from a secure website in iOS5? I'm parsing with `NSJSONSerialization` and this is what the method looks like:

```
- (void)parseJSON {
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"https//:username:password@www.mysecuresite.com"]];
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSArray *items = [json objectForKey:@"projects"];
    [self setTableData:items];
}
```

Otherwise, accessing an unsecured website and returning the parsed json file is OK, just not over a secured site.

Comment: What is going wrong with the code you're using? (error message?) It looks like your URL has an extra colon.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I fixed it, so it's NSURL URLWithString:@"https//username:password@www.mysecuresite.com"]

The error: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil' "

Comment: The problem still persists though...

Comment: Try pasting your URL into a web browser.